# demo python server client interaction

Tags: python, networking

I'm really new to networking in general and I'm trying to set up a simple exchange between a python server and client.

This is the code for the server

```
import socket, ssl

def do_something(connstream, data):
print "HALLO"

def deal_with_client(connstream):
    data = connstream.read()
    # null data means the client is finished with us
    while data:
        if not do_something(connstream, data):
            # we'll assume do_something returns False
            # when we're finished with client
            break
         data = connstream.read()
     # finished with client

bindsocket = socket.socket()
bindsocket.bind(('127.0.0.1', 10024))
bindsocket.listen(5)


while True:
    newsocket, fromaddr = bindsocket.accept()
    print "Setting up connection"
    connstream = ssl.wrap_socket(newsocket,
                             server_side=True,
                             ca_certs=None,
                             certfile="cert.pem",
                             keyfile="privatekey.pem",
                             ssl_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1)
    try:
        deal_with_client(connstream)
    finally:
        connstream.shutdown(socket.SHUT_RDWR)
        connstream.close()
```

Here is the code for the client.py

```
 import socket, ssl

 clientsocket = socket.socket()
 ssl_sock = ssl.wrap_socket(clientsocket,
                       certfile="cert.pem",
                       cert_reqs=ssl.CERT_REQUIRED)
 ssl_sock.connect(('127.0.0.1', 10024))

 print ssl_sock.getpeername()
 print ssl_sock.getpeercert()

 data = ssl_sock.recv(1024)
 ssl_sock.close()

 print 'Received', repr(data)
```

I generated the "cert.pem" and the "privatekey.pem" using openssl.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "server.py", line 30, in <module>
    ssl_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 344, in wrap_socket
    ciphers=ciphers)
   File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 121, in __init__
    self.do_handshake()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 283, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
 ssl.SSLError: [Errno 8] _ssl.c:499: EOF occurred in violation of protocol
```

I was wondering if somehow who knows more could point me in the right direction. I really want to do this using SSL btw, but I would be willing to switch to TLS if that is the better approach.

Comment: There's .... 1000000 examples of this on google.

Answer (score 0):

It could be that the sockets are not running with a compatible ssl version, you should put a "ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1" compatible version in your client too (or removing it from server and use the default value too).
Googling you can find many examples of socket comunication